# I'm trying to hide the buddypress required name profile field, however, I can’t seem to find an answer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, buddypress

The closest I stumbled upon was [this BuddyPress ticke](https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5373)t from 8 years ago which gives this CSS code:

```
#register-page p { display: none;}
#profile-edit-form .field_1 { display: none;}
#signup_form .field_1 { display: none;}
```

to hide the name field and this javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("signup_username").onchange = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("signup_username");
document.getElementById("field_1") .value = x.value
}
</script>
```

to automatically populate the Name field with their BuddyPress username upon registration. To clarify I just want to hide the field from the profile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about specificity.

```
.field_1.field_name.required-field.visibility-public.field_type_textbox {
    display: none;
}
```